# Selenium RC functionality with java

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I am New to selenium RC..already working on selenium IDE. For selenium RC i have chosen java language.also installed selenium rc server.
Now i dont have any idea have to go further. 
Please advice me on same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps.

You have to start the server with

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar
```

And once it is running you can run a java application with something like:

```
Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium( "localhost", 
                                         4444, 
                                         "*firefox", 
                                         "http://www.somesite.com/");

// the code from your Selenium IDE export goes here, e.g.
selenium.open("http://www.somesite.com/somePage.html"); 

selenium.stop();
```

For more information see, the following tutorial:

[Selenium Remote Control For Java — A Tutorial](http://www.bitmotif.com/selenium/selenium-remote-control-for-java-a-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

Export the testcases you have in IDE and use them inside your java program.

Sorry to be that generic, but your question is really vague...

Comment: done with export (java), and also tried to run script > java -jar selenium-server.jar -multiwindow -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://www.google.com" "C:\Selenium_Scripts\test.html" "C:\Selenium_Scripts\results.html"  but its not working...actually i am not aware of flow for executing script on RC

Comment: I don't think you can run a script exported as java from the command line that way.  [The documentation uses a test exported as HTML](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#run-selenese-directly-within-the-server-using-htmlsuite).